# Being beaten to taking the gym back after lowering prestige

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm not sure if this is a glitch, or just an issue caused by slow/unresponsive servers.

I'm in Team Valour, and each time I have lowered a teams prestige to zero resulting in them being evicted from the gym, they are already back in before I have even had a chance to place one of my Pokémon there.

I have done this 3 times at the same gym and it is becoming very frustrating.

Is this an intended mechanic reacting badly to slow servers, or is it a glitch?

Answer (score 3):

When you defeat a gym, your team doesn't gain control of it. The gym becomes neutralized, so any team in the area can take it. You just have to try to act faster, and put a Pokemon in the gym right when you beat it.

**So yes, it is an intended effect.**

Edit, based on comment regarding update:

> Since version 0.45.0/1.15.0, victors now have a short window of time where they can exclusively place a Pokémon in a gym.

Comment: I suspected that it was as intended. Quite frustrating when the loading takes longer than it should.

Comment: Yup, I've had gyms "swooped up" from me multiple times before (and I'm guilty of doing it to others).  
It does make sense though, because otherwise people could win a gym for their team and just wait while to put something in it, rendering the gym useless.

Comment: It does seem like maybe a 60-second "exclusivity" period should be enacted... if I were king of the (Pokemon Go) world...

Comment: That would be the ideal solution, but this is the company that has had ongoing bugs since the game was in beta and still not fixed them.

Comment: Since version 0.45.0/1.15.0, victors now have a short window of time where they can exclusively place a Pokémon in a gym. This answer could probably use an update in light of that.